# How to remove silk screen from PCB?

Tags: pcb, solder-mask, silkscreen

Last batch of PBCs I got from a manufacturer had some silk screen splashes (dots) all over the board ruining the design. I don't have and don't want to have any silk screen on the board. The whole board is covered with solder mask. Is there any way to remove the silk screen without damaging the solder mask?

Comment: If there is unspecified solder mask on pads you should probably reject them as defective rather than make a mess with solvents or scraping.  If it's a prototype you need to run with regardless, consider that, at least with individual manual inspection, solder mask is relatively optional.  Do you have any of these splashes in areas where you absolutely have to preserve solder mask to control reflow?  If so you can probably correct any flaws, tombstoning, or whatever by hand.

Comment: The board doesn't have any components on it at all. It's more like art thing.

Comment: If it is art you can check if the silkscreen splash makes them unique and have more artsy worth. :P